# How to set state from tcomb-form-native from values

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I am trying to set values to state after submitting the form in tcomb-form-native ..  I am new to react native
 Find the code in the image [Check The Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncVRp.png)

Comment: Can you give some of your sample or example code? And clarify your question

Comment: I want to see where are doing setState

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik please check the image which i have added .. u ill find the code

Comment: @MasukHelalAnik can u please check it out

Comment: You have to call some method on onChange

Comment: i have called onchange method....but its not working

Comment: if i set state manually .....the form fields are becoming empty

Comment: Ok, let me try in my computer to check it out

Comment: can you give me your  code to check

Answer (score 1):

First set your states in the constructor in this way and remove the onChange. I think it may work

> this.state = {
>       value:{
>         username:' ',
>         password:' ',
>         organization:' '
>       }